# in a hidden input, how to get the input text value in another input?

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I'm using php.
there're two inputs, aa and bb. aa is a text input which users can input something,  and i want bb (which is a hidden input) is submitted with the input value from aa.
i tried this, however, it seems aa_value is null in input bb when submitting the form. how to implement that?

```
aa_value() {

                $value = '';
                if ( isset( $_POST['aa'] ) )
                        $value = $_POST['aa'];
                echo $value;

}

<input type="text" name="aa" id="aa" value="<?php aa_value(); ?>

<input type="hidden" name="bb" id="bb" value="<?php aa_value(); ?>
```

Comment: PHP is performed before output. So unless `aa_value()` already has a value before the form is even loaded, your hidden input will never have a value.

Comment: Or more easily explained: You can't call for a PHP function before submitting your form. Use a Javascript function instead, or simply remove the hidden input all together and save `$_POST['aa']` in 2 seperate variables on your backend, since they're both the same anyway.

Comment: looks reasonable, however, why there's no problem with the aa?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side language so it will execute before render the html on browser.
You need to use the javascript or jquery to solve the problem.
Use below code on blur or change.

```
<input type="text" name="aa" id="aa" value="<?php aa_value(); ?>

<input type="hidden" name="bb" id="bb" value="<?php aa_value(); ?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#aa').blur(function()
{
$('#bb').val($('#aa').val());
});

});
</script>
```

After submition the form you be able to get the aa and bb values.

Comment: This is the right idea but the wrong event. Use the `input` event instead.

Comment: you mean change $('#aa').blur(function() to $('#aa').input(function()?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the word **function** and change the **echo** to a **return**.

```
<?php
   function aa_value() {
       $value = '';
       if ( isset( $_POST['aa'] ) )
               $value = $_POST['aa'];
       return $value;
   }
 ?>
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: there's no problem with aa by using the echo.

Answer (score 0):

This is tested and works perfectly fine. Change the hidden textfield to a normal one if you wish to see the magic working:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["aa"]) && !empty($_POST["aa"])){
    $value = $_POST["aa"];
} else {
    $value = "";
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Example</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on("change keyup mouseup", "#aa", function(){
                $("#bb").val($("#aa").val());
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="aa" id="aa" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="bb" id="bb" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @wenlujon If your question is answered, please mark the right answer so the question doesn't remain open forever. It's also a way of showing your appreciation to the one that took the time to help you out.